# Extracting array column from spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My spark dataframe has array column, I have to generate new columns by extracting data from single array column. are there any methods available for this.

```
 id  Amount 
 10   [Tax:10,Total:30,excludingTax:20] 
 11   [Total:30] 
 12   [Tax:05,Total:35,excludingTax:30]
```

I have to generate this dataframe.

```
 ID  Tax Total 
 10  10   30   
 11  0    30   
 12  05   35
```

Comment: what's the schema of Amount column ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure [Tax:10,Total:30,excludingTax:20]  are the only fields in the same order you can always map over entire dataframe and extract them as Amount[0], Amount[1] ...

Then assign them as a instance of a case class and finally convert back to dataframe.

Only thing you have to be care full that you don't call Amount[3] if Amount has only 2 values. That is easily achievable by checking the array length.

Alternately if you don't know the order. Best way is to use JSONRdd. Then loop through the JSON object parse them and create a new row. Finally convert that to a dataframe